# Same Role with different actions for different users

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I'm using symfony3 and i have many roles in my application, and i want as an admin to attribute many actions(management books, management projects..) to different users howerver they already have the same role, for example two students can have different management (actions) however they already have the same role "ROLE_STUDENT".
knowing that i used FOSUserBundle for user management. i found many solutions on the internet for example using ACLs, Groups, permissions, use those actions as a roles..
So how can i attribute actions to different users with same role and what's the best solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of role, role hierarchy and voter

```
/** security.yaml **/
    role_hierarchy:
            ROLE_ADMIN
            ROLE_STUDENT_BOOK:       ROLE_STUDENT
            ROLE_STUDENT_PROJECT:     ROLE_STUDENT       
            ROLE_STUDENT_LIBRARY: [ROLE_STUDENT_BOOK, ROLE_STUDENT_PROJECT]
```

Here your user can have a role ROLE_STUDENT_BOOK and manage book, where another student is managing projects and a third manage both... but in the end they are still students with all the permission of the ROLE_STUDENT.And of course none of them has admin privileges

Then you can use voter to have a more precise control on who can do what with your object

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html